# Socket connection in Java

Tags: java, c, sockets, connection, ip

I'm migrating a program, from C to Java. This program have a socket connection, that says something like this:

```
socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

struct sockaddr_in  sa ;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = hostAddr ;
sa.sin_family      = AF_INET ;
sa.sin_port        = htons( ( unsigned short ) atol(obj->Port) ) ;

connect( obj->Socket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &sa, sizeof( sa ) ) ;
```

However, when I try to connect to the server in Java, the connection doesn't work: the connection end in the moment that I send my string with data.
I've searching and asking, and the only difference that I can see, it's that in Java, I don't use a family (AF_INET), I only use the ip and port.

This is my Java code:

```
String ip = "X.X.X.X"; 
Integer port = "yyy";
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

...

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
byte buf[] = toSocket.getBytes();
out.write(buf);
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Seems like somehow your Socket is closing, and my guess that this might be that socket is a method declared variable (as opposed to class/object variable) and that when you leave your method, the socket is garbage collected and closed

Comment: maybe flushing will help

Comment: There is nothing in this Java code that would cause the connection to end. However possibly you are closing the output stream, which does close the socket and termate the connection. @DanielJipa Flushing this stream will do precisely nothing.

Comment: More code and exposition must be posted. Where is it determined that the socket is closed? What is `toSocket` and where did it come from? Does the `out.write(buf)` throw an exception? Etc.